# Why is getting the offsetHeight giving an error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a DIV which has a image slider and I am trying to get the height for to place another DIV underneath.

```
<div id="divss">
   ... image slider contents
</div>
<div id="imgShadow">
    <img src="shadow_below_content.png" />
</div>
```

I am using the following jQuery function to get the height:

```
    $(function () {
         var height = document.getElementById('divss').offsetHeight;
         $("#imgShadow").css('top', height + "px");
    });
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
         var height = document.getElementById('divss').offsetHeight;
         $("#imgShadow").css('top', height + "px");
         //alert(height);
    }).resize();
```

So what happens is when the page loads the shadow image will be right below the divss DIV and on resize whatever the height of the divss div is, the shadow image will be below it.

I am getting an error in the resize function for this line: `var height = document.getElementById('divss').offsetHeight;`

The error is `Object required`.

How do I fix it? Or better yet, how can I always ensure the shadow image is always below the divss div no matter what size the browser is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$(window).resize(function () {
         var height = document.getElementById('divss').offsetHeight;
         $("#imgShadow").css('top', height + "px");
         //alert(height);
    });
```